# Trouble writing Windows cmd script that finds a string in a directory name sets that dir name for use later

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, windows-7

I'm writing a cmd script that will search a server on a mapped drive (`X:`) for a unique string (`very_specific_identifier`) that maps to a single folder. Then I need to set that result to a variable for use later. So far I have the following;

```
set very_specific_identifier=42
set target_dir=dir /b /s X:\server\*%very_specific_identifier%*
```

When I attempt this in running the following after the lines above:

```
%target_dir%
```

I see `target_dir` displayed then the command continues to run for ~20s (calculating the size on disk, I guess, which is ~3GB) then control is returned to me.

```
X:\server\foo_42
:: Blank line while thinking ~20-30s
:: Return to usual command line
```

My question is how can I get a result that I can manipulate or expand later?

Also is there a better faster way to do this?

Comment: `For /f` loops parse command output. See `for /?`. `for /f %A in ('dir /b c:\windows\win.ini') do echo %A`

Comment: You can't set a single variable to an entire directory listing. Use a for loop and iterate to do whatever you need, rather than trying to use a variable. If you must have a single list, pipe the `dir` output to a file.